# Auto get Email bot with google scripts

Tags: html, google-apps-script, gmail

I am making a bot that gets the first email and prints it. This is what I have so far:

.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
}
```

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function mail() {
    var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox
    thread.getMessages()[0]; 
    }
    function text() {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0];
    list.getElementsByClassName("child")[0].innerHTML = mail();
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="example">
    <li class="child">Coffee</li>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="text()">Try it</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

please tell me whats wrong and comment if you need any additional info

Comment: so i should put it in my doGet()?

Comment: No just put in on the server and use google.script.run to access it.  This whole function shoulld be server side.`function mail() {
    var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox
    thread.getMessages()[0]; 
    }` [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: ok I will do that, but before i ever tried to access it( "mail()" ), it said "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.

Please check the address and try again.

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function text() {
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(whatever){
       //do whatever your want with whatever here
    })
    .mail() 
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="example">
    <li class="child">Coffee</li>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="text()">Try it</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs:

```
    function mail() {
     var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox
     thread.getMessages()[0]; 
     //.......
     return whatever;
    }
```

Here's another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60365593/7215091