# HTML Form Select Element Not Allowing Changes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, materialize

I have a form that I am creating for my kids' school and am having issues with the drop-down list to choose the student name. The list is populated via JavaScript code, importing a student list from an associated google sheet. I added a console log for each option as they are created to show that they are in fact being created. Developer options on [the link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxKnhG0ErVgXSIPxczbst4o-J54dHUKC67nA4SegCnx/dev) should reveal that.

Once I load the form I am unable to change the student identifier from the default option. I can't tell what I've done wrong. If I hard code the values into the HTML it works fine, but I want the teacher to be able to add and remove students via the spreadsheet because that is a more user-friendly and flexible implementation.

---

form.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      body {
        background: rgb(244, 235, 234)
      }

      .outer-field {
        border-radius: 15px;
        background: white;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 20px;
      }

      .title {
        padding-left: 2%;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s8 offset-s2 offset-s2">
        <!--Document Header-->
        <div class="outer-field" style="height: 100px">
          <h4>Golden Apple Reader Book Submissions</h4>
        </div>
        <!--Form to submit ISBN and autopopulate title and page count-->
        <form id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); formSubmit(this) ">
          <!--Creates ISBN entry field-->
          <div class="outer-field">
            <div class="title">Book ISBN</div>
            <div class="col s8">
              <div class="input-field">
                <input type="text" id="ISBN" name="ISBN" class="UUID validate" form="myForm">
                <label for="ISBN">ISBN</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Creates button to check ISBN data-->
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="btn" style="margin-left: 3%" type="button" onclick="populateDetails(); return false;">Autofill Book Data From ISBN
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
          </div> 
          
          <!--Creates student name entry field-->
          <div class="outer-field">
            <div class="title">Student Name</div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <select form="myForm" name="StudentID" id="StudentID" required>
                <!--Add student IDs and names here-->
                <!--<option value="212702">John</option>
                <option value="212703">Henry</option>
                <option value="003">003</option>-->
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--Creates book title entry field-->
          <div class="outer-field">
            <div class="title">Book Required Information</div>
            <div class="col s8">
              <div class="input-field">
                <input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" class="name" form="myForm" required>
                <label for="Title">Book Title</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          
          <!--Creates book page count entry field-->
            <div class="col s4">
              <div class="input-field">
                <input type="number" id="PageCount" name="PageCount" class="pages" form="myForm" required>
                <label for="PageCount">Book Page Count</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!--Creates button to submit data-->
          <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" style="margin-left: 3%" >Submit
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
          </button>
        </form>        
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>      
      M.FormSelect.init(document.querySelectorAll('select'));
      
      //function to populate student list element
      (function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function (selectList) {
            var select = document.getElementById('StudentID');
            for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
              //initial attempt commented here for troubleshooting
              //var option = document.createElement('option');
              //option.value = selectList[i][0];
              //option.text = selectList[i][4];
              var option = new Option(selectList[i][4], selectList[i][0]);
              console.log(option);
              select.add(option, undefined);
            }
            console.log(select)
                      }
        ).getSelectList();
      }());

      //Uses the ISBN to populate the book title and page quantity
      function populateDetails(){
        isbn=document.getElementById('ISBN').value;
        //isbn=9781492680550;//for debugging only
        var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?country=US&q=isbn:" + isbn;
        var obj
        var title="No Entry Identified";
        var pageCount=0;
        var titleout=document.getElementById('Title');
        var pageout=document.getElementById('PageCount');
        //fetches URL data from google books API
        fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => obj = data)
          .then(
              function(settitle){
                //Assigns title to variable and text field
                title = obj.items[0].volumeInfo.title
                titleout.value=title;
                titleout.focus();
              },
              function(titlerror){
              })
          .then(
            function(setpages){
              //Assigns page count to variable and text field
              pageCount = obj.items[0].volumeInfo.pageCount
              pageout.value=pageCount;
              pageout.focus();
            },
            function(pageerror){
            })
        //In the case that no entry is found in google books API, assigns default values to text fields and deconflicts the overlapping label and value fields
        titleout.value=title;
        titleout.focus();
        pageout.value=pageCount;
        pageout.focus();
      }
      
      //Submits form data to spreadsheet
      function formSubmit (data) {        
        var dataToSubmit = {
          studentID: data.StudentID.value,
          title: data.Title.value,
          pageCount: data.PageCount.value
        }
        //Provides a success message to the user
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function () {
              myForm.reset()
              M.toast({html: "Thank you! You have successfully submitted!"})
            }).submitData(dataToSubmit)
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

code.gs code

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Submissions")
var ss2= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Students")
var last=ss2.getLastRow();
var students=ss2.getRange(2,1,last-1,5).getValues();
function getSelectList() {
  try {    
    return students;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form').evaluate().addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
}

function submitData (data) {  
  ss.appendRow([new Date(),data.studentID, data.title, data.pageCount])
}
```

---

spreadsheet content:

| Student ID Number | Student Name | Teacher Name | Grade | Concatenation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UNK1 | John | TeacherA | K | Grade: K, Teacher: TeacherA, Name: John |
| UNK2 | Henry | TeacherA | K | Grade: K, Teacher: TeacherA, Name: Henry |
| UNK3 | Paige | TeacherA | K | Grade: K, Teacher: TeacherA, Name: Paige |
| UNK4 | Raelyn | TeacherA | K | Grade: K, Teacher: TeacherA, Name: Raelyn |
| UNK5 | Danielle | TeacherA | K | Grade: K, Teacher: TeacherA, Name: Danielle |
| UNK6 | Olivia | TeacherA | K | Grade: K, Teacher: TeacherA, Name: Olivia |

Comment: I recommend that you start with a simple example that only has a select on it and try to get that to work.

Comment: You should provide [mcve] and not the entire project. I think this has to do with material. You probably should initiate or set it to work after adding the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60365593/7215091

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your script, I thought that there is a modification point. Please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
M.FormSelect.init(document.querySelectorAll('select'));

//function to populate student list element
(function () {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
    function (selectList) {
      var select = document.getElementById('StudentID');
      for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
        //initial attempt commented here for troubleshooting
        //var option = document.createElement('option');
        //option.value = selectList[i][0];
        //option.text = selectList[i][4];
        var option = new Option(selectList[i][4], selectList[i][0]);
        console.log(option);
        select.add(option, undefined);
      }
      console.log(select)
                }
  ).getSelectList();
}());
```

#### To:

```
//function to populate student list element
(function () {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
    function (selectList) {
      var select = document.getElementById('StudentID');
      for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
        //initial attempt commented here for troubleshooting
        //var option = document.createElement('option');
        //option.value = selectList[i][0];
        //option.text = selectList[i][4];
        var option = new Option(selectList[i][4], selectList[i][0]);
        console.log(option);
        select.add(option, undefined);
      }
      console.log(select)
      M.FormSelect.init(document.querySelectorAll('select')); // Moved.
    }
  ).getSelectList();
}());
```

- In this modification, `M.FormSelect.init(document.querySelectorAll('select'))` was moved.
- I thought that `(function () {` and `}());` might be not required to be used.